# Determining why my proof depends on the axiom of choice

Tags: lean, constructive, axiom-of-choice

I would like to write constructive proofs in Lean 4, so I don't want my proofs to depend on `Classical.choice`, the axiom of choice. However, one of my proofs does, as shown by the command `#print axioms substring_unpack`, and it's not obvious to me why that is. I have removed tactics like `omega` and `by_cases` which I know may rely on `choice`, but it's possible that a `simp` somewhere is pulling in a lemma which depends on `choice`.

The proof is quite long.

How can I determine where this axiom is being snuck in?

Comment: Not a very elegant solution, but try to replace part of your proof by `sorry` and see what happens. Of course this will add `sorry` as an axiom, but at some point `choice` should disappear.

Comment: I would even start by replacing the full proof by `sorry`, to check that the statement doesn't somehow uses choice.

Comment: I hate to say, this but the are many ways the axiom of choice can sneak into a Lean proof.  Trying to do constructive math in Lean 4 is very painful.

Comment: Well, if you start using a lot of mathlib then I agree, but otherwise it should be more or less fine.

Comment: @Ricky.  No.  It is true in even base lean.  Macros, automatic termination proofs, and common tactics can all add choice unexpectedly.

Comment: You could tell us what you proved and we're going to guess where you used Dependent choice (and whether the use was necessary).

Answer (score 3):

I tried to replace parts of the proof with `sorry`, but I was getting confused by the results of doing so, so I made a small `private lemma` with the part of the proof that seemed to be at issue, and again tried to replace parts of the smaller proof with `sorry`.

I again got confused, so I tried to `print` my lemma and copied and pasted the output of `print` and renamed the resulting lemma. It didn't actually type-check, but I put in a few more `sorry`s and got something that type-checked. Then I replaced more and more of the raw proof term with `sorry` until I had narrowed it down further.

At some point I stumbled on a clue, and realised that I needed to `set_option pp.all true` to see the full (gory) details.

It turned out that I had indeed relied on a theorem from Mathlib - and while this theorem itself did not rely on the axiom of choice, my *use* of it did, because it implicitly summoned into play some type class instances which did. After some digging I found that:

`OrderedCancelAddCommMonoid.toContravariantClassLeft`

was a/the culprit, which uses

`contravariant_lt_of_contravariant_le`

which uses

`contravariant_le_iff_contravariant_lt_and_eq`

which uses

`LE.le.lt_or_eq`, which is an alias for `lt_or_eq_of_le`

which uses

`Classical.propDecidable` which says that all Props are Decidable (with my constructivist hat on I disagree with this!)

which uses

`Classical.em`, the law of the excluded middle

which uses

`Classical.choose`

which uses

`Classical.indefiniteDescription`, which uses the axiom of choice (in some way I don't understand)

My plan of attack now is to use constructive instances, or define them myself if they don't already exist, using [priority](https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/type_classes.html) to ensure they are picked up first.

Comment: Is it a huge secret what it is that you're proving? Perhaps someone already did it in one of the constructively valid proof assistants. And also, what's the point of formalizing constructive math in a proof assistant that is riddled with secret sneaky uses of choice and excluded middle?

Comment: Your persistence is admirable.

Comment: Aside: `Classical.indefiniteDescription` is just another name for the axiom of choice.

Comment: `Classical.propDecidable` also directly uses `choice`. `Classical.indefiniteDescription` and `choice` both lift Prop to Type*, and they are equivalent without axioms.